# Function that returns a value in extensions.conf - asterisk

Tags: asterisk, telephony

I want to do the following in my extensions.conf in asterisk:

1. Read in a number entered by a user. - easy
2. Feed that number into a script which returns a wav file.
3. This wav file is then played.

I know the `system` command, but have not been able to figure out a way for it to return a value.

Any help is most welcome,
Thanks,
Sriram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can have the program/script write the value to a file and then use the functions within asterisk such as `ReadFile` to get the value. This can be done like so:

Within the script:
`echo -n ${value} > ${fileName}`

From within asterisk:
`exten => 0,n,ReadFile(ValueReadFromFile=${fileName},${MAX_FILE_CHAR})`

where: `${MAX_FILE_CHAR}` is the max. characters that need to be read from the file `${fileName}`. The value you want read will be stored in `ValueReadFromFile`.

Answer (score 1):

For such things I use [Asterisk AGI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI). Idea is similar to CGI scripts for Web servers. You can use various languages, but I use Python with [pyst: Python for Asterisk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyst/) library. Such AGI script/program can read or set channel variable and this way communicate with Asterisk dialplan.

Example of such code with `pyst agilib`:

```
wav_to_play = 'other.wav'
user_nr = agilib.get_variable('user_entered_number')
if not user_nr:
    wav_to_play = 'nothing.wav'
elif user_nr.endswith('0'):
    wav_to_play = 'zero.wav'
# ...
agilib.set_variable('wav_selected', wav_to_play)
```

After saving such code in `wav_selector.agi` (you must add normal Python header, libs etc) you can use it in dialplan like:

```
exten => s,n,Set(user_entered_number=5)
exten => s,n,AGI(wav_selector.agi)
exten => s,n,Background((${wav_selected})
```